# GraphicsMagick in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, media

`D7` has `ImageAPI` and that `ImageMagick Module` is also installed. However I want to use `GraphicsMagick` with D7 but haven't been successful till now. I have both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick installed in my Ubuntu Box, I also have `pecl imagick` and `pecl gmagick` installed. I know both `pecls` doesn't work at the same time, but I have been changing configs whenever necessary.

I have tested both `ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick` from command line, both works perfectly, but I couldn't make it work with `Drupal`. According to `ImageMagick Module` I just need to change in `Image Toolkit` from `convert` to `gm`, Drupal reads the `executable binary` perfectly. I try to upload photo which doesn't show after processing and is also not uploaded in the file. But when I change it back to `convert` and `pecl imagick` everything works smoothly.

Any suggestions how to use `GraphicsMagick` with `Drupal 7` ?

I even tried that this http://drupal.org/sandbox/W32/1077458 sandbox project, but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, but for future reference, the problem might be related to the fact that you are using the PECL gmagick PHP extension. I believe the ImageMagick module is not meant to work with the gmagick PHP extension. There is a module meant to be used specifically with PECL's gmagick: https://www.drupal.org/project/gmagick . I hope that helps somebody.